# Mouse not working/lagging at startup

Tags: mouse, startup

I am on ubuntu LTS 22.04. I installed ubuntu a few days ago and it was working perfectly on initial install. I restarted the Laptop and it boots perfectly normal but the mouse doesn't work (when it does it's extremely lagging to the point it is unusable). The strange thing is it works like normal once i put the computer to sleep and then turn it on again. This is a specific problem and i couldn't find the solution anywhere, hence me posting here. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the synaptics driver but that didn't work.

Laptop : Lenovo Ideapad 330-15igm (model: 81D1009LUS)
Intel celeron N4000
4Gb ram

Comment: It might help if you specify your laptop and mouse models.

Comment: Indeed. Please [edit] the question and post hardware specifications. That said, I would suggest updating UEFI, if available, before anything else.

Comment: @blnks i added laptop model but couldn't find my mouse model.

Comment: Are you talking about the laptop's own track pad, or an external mouse? If it is an external, is it wireless or wired?

Comment: @ChanganAuto UEFI is already updated

Comment: @blnks the laptops own trackpad